# java wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I'm taking one Integer variable and sharing with two threads. One thread should print even numbers and one thread should print odd number sequentially.
But notify() throwing IllegalMonitorStateException.

```
package mywaitnotifytest;
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i=0;
        Even even = new Even(i);
        even.setName("EvenThread");
        Odd odd = new Odd(i);
        odd.setName("OddThread");
        even.start();
        odd.start();
    }
}

class Even extends Thread{

    Integer var;

    Even(Integer var){
        this.var=var;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            synchronized (var) {
                if(var%2==0){
                    try {
                        var.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                var++;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  "+var);
                var.notify();
            }
        }

    }
}

class Odd extends Thread{

    Integer var;

    Odd(Integer var){
        this.var=var;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            synchronized (var) {
                if(var%2!=0){
                    try {
                        var.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                var++;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"  "+var);
                var.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is :

OddThread  1

```
Exception in thread "OddThread" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)

at mywaitnotifytest.Odd.run(App.java:67)
```

Comment: This question seems different as OP is getting exception on `notify`, not `wait`. Plus the reason of the exception is quite different and as nothing to do with non `synchronized` code

Comment: You are not calling `notify()` on the same object as you locked.  In short, don't lock on a mutable field. When you mutate it you change it.  Also don't lock on a pooled object, as `Integer` is as this will have confusing consequences.

Comment: I'm calling wait and notify from synchronized block only

Comment: @ortis while the OP is using `synchornized` he/she is not  calling notify on an object they have `synchronized`.

Comment: @NareshMuthyala Using `synchronized` means you have to call `notify`/`wait` on the same object. It doesn't give you permission to lock on any object.

Comment: For the above requirement what is the edit suggested in the code? How do i share the same object for multiple threads?

Comment: I have added how I would do it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is sufficiently different to the usual answer to give another one.

In this case you are using `synchronized`. When you apply a lock it is on a object not a reference.

---

```
synchronized (var) {
```

This locks the object `var` references, not on `var` as a field.

---

```
var++;
```

This replaces the object `var` points to. It is the same as

```
var = Integer.valueOf(var.intValue() + 1);
```

Note: `Integer` and indeed all the primitive wrappers are Immutable.  When you perform any operation on them you are actually unboxing, calculating using the primitive value and re-boxing the object. It is possible to get the same object back if it is pooled. e.g.

```
Integer i = 10;
i += 0; // gives back the same object.
```

However, if the object is not pooled

```
Double d = 10;
d += 0; // creates a new object.
```

---

```
var.notify();
```

Attempts the call `notify` on the new object, not the one which was locked.

---

You shouldn't attempt to lock a field which you mutate. It won't do what it appears to do.  You also shouldn't lock on a pooled object.  In this case you could have another thread using the same `Integer` for an unrelated purpose and `notify()` will wake up an unrelated thread.

To use wait/notify correctly, you should

- `notify()` or `notifyAll()` after a state change in another shared field.
- you should use a while loop for `wait()` to check the state change.

If you don't do this

- notify can be lost if another thread is not waiting.
- wait can wake spuriously, even when no notify was called.

> For the above requirement what is the edit suggested in the code? How do i share the same object for multiple threads?

```
public class PingPong implements Runnable {    
    static class Shared { int num; }

    private final Shared var;
    private final int bit;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shared var = new Shared();
        new Thread(new PingPong(var, 0), "EvenThread").start();
        new Thread(new PingPong(var, 1), "OddThread").start();
    }

    PingPong(Shared var, int bit) {
        this.var = var;
        this.bit = bit;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            while (true) {
                synchronized (var) {
                    while (var.num % 2 == bit)
                        var.wait();

                    var.num++;
                    System.out.println(name + "  " + var.num);
                    var.notify();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why you should always use `final` when dealing with `synchronized`, `wait`, or `notify`

Comment: @ortis where ever possible, with serialize objects it's not always possible to use `final` but the field should be effectively final. +1

Comment: Upvoted this answer. Explains how wait should be used (in a while(conditionNotMet) {waitOnTheLockObject;}). This answer should be accepted. @PeterLawrey, along with this, if you edit and explicitly mention that all wrapper classes for primitives are immutable, it will be nice. It will explain why var++ on Integer will create a new Integer object (explicitly).

Comment: @Amudhan added a bit more explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using Integer wrapper class,I created my own class and now It works fine.

```
package mywaitnotifytest;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyInt i = new MyInt(0);
        Even even = new Even(i);
        even.setName("EvenThread");
        Odd odd = new Odd(i);
        odd.setName("OddThread");
        even.start();
        odd.start();
    }
}

class Even extends Thread {

    MyInt var;

    Even(MyInt var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (var) {
                if (var.i % 2 == 0) {
                    try {
                        var.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                var.i++;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "  " + var.i);
                var.notify();
            }
        }

    }

}

class Odd extends Thread {
    MyInt var;

    Odd(MyInt var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (var) {
                if (var.i % 2 != 0) {
                    try {
                        var.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                var.i++;
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "   " + var.i);
                var.notify();

            }
        }

    }
}

class MyInt {
    int i = 0;

    public MyInt(int i) {
        super();
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "" + i;
    }

}
```

Comment: Posting an workaround without explaining the cause of the original problem is useless for readers. Please accept the above answer.